# Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't boot up - num lock blinking

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I'm dual booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04. But today, when I turned on my laptop, I saw the plymouth boot screen and then the screen was blank, with a small "line" at the upper left edge of the screen. One thing I noticed was blinking num lock key.

After about 10 minutes, the num lock key stopped blinking and the "line" or cursor too. It stuck for about 30 minutes now.

**What I've tried:**

- Reboot
- Use older kernel

**EDIT**

When I press the power button, Ubuntu will shut down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, it was because of full disk usage. If you have these issues too, here's how to fix it:

1. Boot into recovery mode.
2. Choose root console.
3. Use the command line to find and delete large files you don't need.
4. Reboot and check if it helped.